# 'this' returns global scope in Keyboard listeners events

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to listen for keyboard on/off events, using the Keyboard module from 'react-native', the listeners work but on the receiver I can't access the state because 'this' references the global score instead of this component's 'this'.

```
export default class SignupEmailScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            emailText: '',
            continueTextFadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0.4),
            continueText: emailInvalidText,
            bottomLocation: Layout.window.height,
        };
        console.log(this)
    }


    componentWillMount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
        this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
    }

    _keyboardDidShow(endCoordinates) {
        console.log(this)
    }

    _keyboardDidHide() {
    }

    ...
}
```

The first `console.log(this)` in the constructor logs as excepted:
[image]
But the second one in the `keyboardDidShow()` logs this (it goes on):
[image]

**Question:** How can I change the state in the keyboard listeners?

Is this because the keyboard listeners functions may be actually static?

Comment: just define your function like: `_keyboardDidShow = (endCoordinates) => { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to bind the scope when passing a method reference and calling that method in some other context. You can use `bind` like this:

```
this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
```

Alternatively, you can use arrow functions that preserves the context of "this" keyword.

```
this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', () => {
    this._keyboardDidShow(<method params>)
});
```